# Full page scroll with parallax effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I want to make a full page scroll effect like [this site](https://codeless.co/folie/portfolio-product-fullscreen/) or [this site](https://codyhouse.co/gem/page-scroll-effects) (demo [here](https://codyhouse.co/demo/page-scroll-effects/index.html)).

It seems that divs are moving in the different speed or kind of some acceleration so that the later `div` may scroll first and the `div` before may scroll later, and makes the later `div` becomes like a mask that will hide the before `div` for a little while.

I tried to use `scrollIntoView` with `smooth` behavior like [this](http://www.kodhus.com/kodnest/codify/yhxQeaX/layout/1):

```js
const content = document.querySelectorAll('section');
let index = 0;
document.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
  var delta = event.wheelDelta;
  if (delta < 0) {
    index++;
    content.forEach((section, i) => {
      if (i === index) {
        toggleText(i, 'show');
        section.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
      }
    })
  } else {
    index--;
    content.forEach((section, i) => {
      if (i === index) {
        toggleText(i, 'show');
        section.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Now when scroll event fires, each `section` moves in the same speed, and the later `section` cannot hide the before `section` for a little while.

How to implement this "mask" like effect?

Comment: take some time forming your question, otherwise theres a good chance ppl wont understand your question lol

Comment: A great example [here](https://codepen.io/suez/full/ByvKXE).

Comment: tag me to remind me about this and i may help u out when i get a minute over the next few days

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this would just to add delays after clicking `next` or `prev`

```
var delay = 2500; //2.5 second

setTimeout(function() {
  //your code here
}, delay);
```

Your code will execute in 2.5 seconds.